# No. of ways of choosing 4 people from 6 couples

Tags: combinatorics

Question: $4$ people are to be chosen from $6$ married couples such that there is exactly one married couple in the group.

For this question I first chose one married couple out of the $6$ : $\binom{6}{1}$.
Then the number of people left are 10. Now choosing one from these: $\binom{10}{1}$.
Now I can choose from $8$ other people (as one of them will be married to the one chosen above):$\binom{8}{1}$

So ultimately the number of ways is: $\binom{6}{1}\cdot\binom{10}{1}\cdot\binom{8}{1} = 480$.

But the answer is $240$. Where is my logic flawed?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are double counting the final two (unmarried) people you chose; if you choose Linus and then Lucy, that's the same as choosing Lucy and then Linus. So you want $6(10\cdot8/2)$.

Comment: See my comment to uniquesolution's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is in the last two steps. Imagine you first selected the first partner from the first couple (arbitrary choice) out of ten people, and then the second partner from the second couple out of eight people. The result would be the same as when you would first have chosen the second partner from the second couple, and then the first partner from the first. Thus, you must divide by $2$ to account for this.

Comment: Oh ok. I understand my mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way to count the number of possibilities is as follows: Having chosen one (mandatory) married couple, we are left with $5$ couples, of which we must choose $2$ couples, out of each of which we must choose one person only. So the number of possibilities is
$$6\times {5\choose 2}\times 4 = 240$$

Comment: +1 nice.  I favor your approach, because it prevents **double-counting** *up-front*.  The alternative is to adopt a counting method that permits double-counting, recognize the defect, and then compensate by applying a scaling factor (i.e. scaling factor $= \frac{1}{2}$) *after the fact*.