# No. of ways of choosing 4 people from 6 married couples such that no 2 people are husband or wife of each other.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Question: Find the number of ways of choosing 4 people from 6 married couples such that no 2 people are husband or wife of each other.

My teacher solved it as under:

${6\choose 4}.{2\choose 1}.{2\choose 1}.{2\choose 1}.{2\choose 1} =240$.

That is, choosing four couples out of 6 couples then choosing exactly one member (a husband or a wife) from each couple.
I fully understood the logic.

But, on myself, I proceeded as:

(Choosing 1 member from 6 husbands × choosing 3 members from 5 wives {excluding wife of the chosen husband}) $+$

(choosing 2 out of 6 husbands × choosing 2 out of 5 wives) $+$

(choosing 3 out of 6 husbands × choosing 1 out of 5 wives) $+$

(choosing 4 out of 6 husbands × choosing 0 out of 6 wives)$+$

(choosing 0 out of 6 husbands × choosing 4 out of 6 wives)

= ${6\choose 1}{5\choose 3}+{6\choose 2}{5\choose 2}+{6\choose 3}{5\choose 1}+{6\choose 4}{6\choose 0}+{6\choose 0}{6\choose 4}
 =340$

Please help me know as to where my logic is flawed. It would be very kind of you.

Comment: This question was closed, stating "This question needs details or clarity". I corrected " no two people are husband and wife" to "no two people are husband or wife of each other". I request intellectuals having a reopening vote and moderators to help reopen my question.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is correct; the numbers used are not.  For $k\in[[0..4]]$ you want to select $k$ from $6$ husbands and $4-k$ from the $6-k$ wives not married to the chosen husbands.

$$\def\C#1#2{\operatorname{^{#1}\mathrm C_{#2}}}\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^4\C6k\C{6-k}{4-k}~&=~\C 60\C64+\C61\C53+\C62\C42+\C63\C31+\C64\C20\\&= 240\end{align}$$

Comment: I am extremely thankful to you. This doubt was teasing my mind for 3 days. Many many thanks to you sir.

Comment: Will you please help me understand the flaw of the OP in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3863924/no-of-ways-of-choosing-4-people-from-6-couples?r=Saves_AllUserSaves. I am not getting the flaws pointed out by other people.

Comment: @Samarpan $\binom 61\binom{10}1\binom81$, or $\binom61\binom22\cdot\binom51\binom21\cdot\binom41\binom21$, counts ways to choose a couple and 2 uncoupled people, but (as was pointed out) this overcounts because you should be unconcerned about the order in which the uncoupled people are selected.   Rather you wish to select *both* from one couple, and *one each* from *two other* couples: $\binom 62\binom 22\cdot\binom 52\binom 21^2$.

Comment: Now, I have fully understood the logic, thanks to your minute but profound description.

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher is correct.

Another way to get the correct answer is to skip by twos, thus $12*10*8*6/4!$, the divisor needed as we don't care about the order in which we chose

Your attempt is unnecessarily complex, due to which you are not able to correctly count choosable wives.

Comment: I have now understood the flaw in my solution. I just put in wrong digits as Graham Kemp pointed out.

Comment: True, there's nothing wrong in the approach itself, but the simpler the approach, the better !

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to use the principle of inclusion-exclusion.  First select $4$ people from $12$, then subtract for each choice of selected married couple, then add back in for each choice of two married couples, yielding
$$\binom{12}{4}-\binom{6}{1}\binom{12-2}{4-2}+\binom{6}{2}\binom{12-4}{4-4}=495-6\cdot45+15\cdot1=240.$$

Answer (score 0):

How many different types of *quads* are there?

$(m + f)^4 = ^4C_4 m^4 + ^4C_3 m^3 f + ^4C_2 m^2 f^2 + ^4C_1 mf^3 + ^4C_0 f^4$

For $m^4$, we have $^6C_4$

For $m^3 f$, we have $^6 C_3 \cdot ^5C_1$

For $m^2 f^2$, we have $^6C_2 \cdot ^4C_2$

For $m f^3$, we have $^6C_1 \cdot ^5C_3$

For $f^4$, we have $^6C_0 \cdot ^6C_4$

Add 'em all up.